# My python script can't see the attachments attached to an issue with jira-python

Tags: python-jira

I've made a python script that creates Jira issues and attach a file to them.

This part works fine and I can see the attachment directly in Jira. I can also see the attachment in my Python script if I reference directly the attachment ID (that I've found in the Jira page of my issue) with that bit of code :

```
att = jira.attachment(116328)
print att
```

But if I open the issue in my Python script, I won't see any attachment attached to it :

```
issue = jira.issue('ARR-10')
print issue.fields.attachment
```

Will return : AttributeError: type object 'PropertyHolder' has no attribute 'attachment'

I was using the version 1.0.10 and upgraded to 2.0.0, but it didn't make a difference.

I'm sure that the issue I'm looking up has an attachment, I just can't understand why there are no attachment attributes. I've checked the "Questions that may already have your answer" but none of them are helping.

Thanks !

Comment: Is the Attachments field set to "Hidden" in your field configuration of the project?

Comment: @FLeX I talked with our admins and that was indeed the problem. Thank you very much !

Comment: lovely! I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jira REST API doesn't return fields that are hidden in the field configuration. Verify that the `Attachments` field is not hidden in the field configuration.

Source: [Fetching an Issue Via API Does Not Return All fields](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/fetching-an-issue-via-api-does-not-return-all-fields-278694956.html)